# Switching fas fa icon through javascript - Dark / Light mode

Tags: html, jquery, css

Don't know where I am going wrong, but the icon just doesn't change.

```js
$( ".inner-switch" ).on("click", function() {
    if( $( "body" ).hasClass( "dark" )) {
      $( "nav" ).removeClass( "dark-force" );
      $( "body" ).removeClass( "dark" );
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fas fa-moon");
    } else {
      $( "body" ).addClass( "dark" );
      $( "nav" ).addClass( "dark-force" );
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fas fa-sun");
    }
});
```

```css
.dark {
    background-color: #222;
}

.dark-force * {
    background-color: #222;
}
```

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-brand">

          <a href="/">
            <img src="{% static 'portfolio/Logo.png' %}" width=60>
          </a>

          <div class="navbar-end">

            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary is-rounded is-outlined">
                  <strong>Blog</strong>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary is-rounded">
                  <strong>Say Hello!</strong>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary is-rounded inner-switch">
                  <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

It does switch to dark mode, but the icon refuses to change from the moon(`fas fa-moon`). I'm new to javascript but fairly familiar with HTML and CSS. Any help is appreciated. Have a great and safe day! Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *nearly* there and your code looks **good** but you need to use `addClass` and `removeClass` to switch `fas fa` icon from `sun` to `moon` and `vice versa`.

```
$(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-sun").addClass('fa-moon');
```

When you use `toggleClass` the existing is still there and new icon is not working as it suppose to.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(".inner-switch").on("click", function() {
  if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
    $("nav").removeClass("dark-force");
    $("body").removeClass("dark");
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-sun").addClass('fa-moon');
  } else {
    $("body").addClass("dark");
    $("nav").addClass("dark-force");
    $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-moon").addClass('fa-sun');
  }
});
```

```css
.dark {
  background-color: #222;
}

.dark-force * {
  background-color: #222;
}

.fa-sun {
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button is-primary is-rounded inner-switch is-outlined">
      <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This method for some reason isn't working. I updated the HTML code to show more code to see if something could be interrupting this process.

Comment: @RohitManjunath Its working perfectly with that HTML as well. Nothing is wrong. Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/tjac3Lsm/ - Let me know.

Comment: Yup, when I run it separately it works. The second I integrate it into Django it stops working! Thanks for the help, I will work on some fix for it! Cheers.

Comment: @RohitManjunath Sure. I think the way djando handle it might be different. But this works perfectly as you know. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only toggle the sun and moon class every second time.
You need to **toggle them both** every time!

```
$(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-moon").toggleClass("fa-sun");
```

FYI you don't need to toggle the `fas` class because you always need it. Also, you don't need to duplicate the code by putting this inside the `if`/`else` - as you need to toggle them both every time you click, you can just include this line once directly in the function.

**Working example:**

```js
$(".inner-switch").on("click", function() {
  // toggle moon and sun every time
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-moon").toggleClass("fa-sun");

  if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
    $("nav").removeClass("dark-force");
    $("body").removeClass("dark");
} else {
 $("body").addClass("dark");
    $("nav").addClass("dark-force");
  }
});
```

```css
.dark {
  background-color: #222;
}

.dark-force * {
  background-color: #222;
}

.button {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #f00
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<div class="navbar-item">
  <div class="buttons">
    <a class="button is-primary is-rounded inner-switch is-outlined">
      <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This method for some reason isn't working. I updated the HTML code to show more code to see if something could be interrupting this process.

Comment: @RohitManjunath you can see this solution works - as with the other answers here that you also commented on as not working - so it is something in your existing project that is interfering with this code. However without knowing anything about about your setup we can't really offer any help with what that might be.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to toggle the font color when you toggle the background color.

```js
$("#lightswitch i").click(function() {
    var isDark = $("body").is(".dark");
    $("body").toggleClass("dark", !isDark);
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-moon", isDark).toggleClass("fa-sun", !isDark);
});
```

```css
body.dark {
  background-color: #222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />

<body>
  <div class="navbar-item">
    <div class="buttons">
      <a id="lightswitch" class="button is-primary is-rounded inner-switch is-outlined">
        <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
       </a>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This method for some reason isn't working. I updated the HTML code to show more code to see if something could be interrupting this process.

Comment: @RohitManjunath You can see that it's working when you click the "Run code snippet" button. You probably can't copy and paste it. Reading it, understanding it, and adapting it to your own situation is still required.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that. There is something wrong when I am integrating it with the Django framework then. Thanks for the help though!